# pgfplots - 3d plots with overwritten lines

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

#### Hello There

Certain 3d graphs plotted with `pgfplots` have lines and planes that should be hidden but are showing in front of the front lines and planes, how to fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        % Hiperbole
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity      = 0.5,
            fill opacity = 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader = faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = 0:360,
        ](
            {cosh(u)*cos(v)},
            {cosh(u)*sin(v)},
            {sinh(u)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        % Elipse
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

generates the following picture, without the annotations in cyan that indicate the problem:
[image: Print of generated pdf with indications of the problem]

Comment: What about a higher value in opacity?

Comment: `opacity` in the configurations is set for the lines only, not for the planes, which its opacity is `1` in other words, no transparency what so ever

Comment: Thanks for making clear @DJ9 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the z buffer - `z buffer=sort`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        % Hiperbole
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity      = 0.5,
            fill opacity = 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader = faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = 0:360,
             z buffer=sort,
        ](
            {cosh(u)*cos(v)},
            {cosh(u)*sin(v)},
            {sinh(u)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        % Elipse
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
             z buffer=sort,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Hyperboloid and sphere]

Comment: very nice it works, is there a way to set it as default in all plots without having to add it individually?

Comment: Yes - just add is as an option to `axis` along with other options that for certain are the same for all plots.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that? i coudn't understand from your comment alone

Comment: `\begin{axis}[hide axis, z buffer=sort]`

Comment: oh i see, well then what i actually wanted is a way to not need to specify that for every `graph/axis/tickzpicture` something that would perhaps fit inside `\pgfplotsset`? i've tried to add it as it is, but generates error

Comment: Yes you can also add it to `\pgfplotsset`, but note that there is a reason(mainly performance) that this is not the default behaviour in PGFPlots, so it should only be used when needed. Please upvote/accept answer.

Comment: How would it be added to `\pgfplotsset`, i've tried to add it the way it is `z buffer=sort`, but generates an error and it wont compile any longer.

Comment: Generated error: `! Package pgfplots Error: No such element: \pgfplotsarrayselect-1\of{pgfpl@cm@cool@X}.`, now im testing in the `axis` and `addplot3` environments and the same error appears

Comment: Its a problem with `multicols` environment, ill try to solve that in another question

Comment: Turns out the problem actually is in the interaction of `colormap` and `z buffer`, i've created another question to take care of that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631589/pgfplots-colormap-and-z-buffer-interference)