# pgfplots - colormap and z buffer interference

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

#### Hello there

Trying to add the option `z buffer = {sort}` to a graph using a custom `colormap` generates an error:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat       = newest,
    width        = .95\linewidth,   % width
    height       = .22\textheight,  % height
    samples      = 20,
    % Color Map
    colormap = {cool}{
        color(0cm)=(green!70!white!40!black);
        color(2cm)=(green!70!white!70!black);
        color(5cm)=(green!70!white!90!black)
    },
}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    height = 0.4\pageheight, 
    width  = 0.4\textwidth,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        hide axis,
        z buffer = {sort},
    ]
        
        % Hiperbole
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity      = 0.5,
            fill opacity = 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader = faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            samples = 10,
            % Variable
            variable   = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = 0:360,
        ](
            {cosh(u)*cos(v)},
            {cosh(u)*sin(v)},
            {sinh(u)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Having both `colormap` definition and `z buffer` option activated at the same time generates several errors:

```
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Package pgfplots Error: No such element: \pgfplotsarrayselect-1\of{pgfpl@cm@cool@X}.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: You can't use `the letter b' after \advance.
<argument> ...olormapfind@rgb@X@left \advance \c@pgf@counta b
                                                  y1 \ifnum \c@pgf@counta <\...
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
<
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\pgfplotscolormapfind@rgb@X@left 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\pgfplotscolormapfind@rgb@X@left 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\pgfplotscolormapfind@rgb@X@left 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\pgfplotscolormapfind@rgb@X@left 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 

/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `67.37263' by `0.0', but I cannot divide any number by `0.0'.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Arithmetic overflow.
\pgfmathdivide@ ...\pgfmath@x by\c@pgfmath@counta 
                                                  \else \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@...
l.56     \end{axis}
                 

/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Package pgfplots Error: No such element: \pgfplotsarrayselect-1\of{pgfpl@cm@cool}.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: You can't use `the letter b' after \advance.
\pgfplotscolormapfind@precomputed@ ...pgf@counta b
                                                  y1 \ifnum \c@pgf@counta <\...
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
<
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:56: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.56     \end{axis}
                 
Runaway argument?
\pgfplots@EOI \relax \pgffor@continuefalse \fi \fi \ifx \pgfplots@markers@visphase@name \ETC.
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:58: Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@loc@TMPb was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.58 
   
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Improper \prevdepth.
\newpage ...everypar {}\fi \par \ifdim \prevdepth 
                                                  >\z@ \vskip -\ifdim \prevd...
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.59 \end{document}
                 
/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.59 \end{document}
                 

/Users/stack q/stack_q.tex:59: LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 27 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.59 \end{document}
                 
(./.build/stack_q.aux))
(\end occurred inside a group at level 3)

### semi simple group (level 3) entered at line 28 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 27 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 27 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 56 was incomplete)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in PGFPlots, when using nonuniform colormaps. The offsets are mapped to the interval 0-1000 starting with the first offset and ending with the last offset, so in your case:

```
0cm -> 0
2cm -> 400
5cm -> 1000
```

These numbers are the ones that are used to choose the colors. They differ very little from a uniform color map(0,500,1000), so I doubt that the non-uniformity is perceivable. If the look seems too bright/dark, the colors themselves can be adjusted or more colors can be added to the list.

Here is a uniform version of your graph:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
z buffer=sort,
colormap={mycool}{
  color=(green!70!white!40!black)
  color=(green!70!white!70!black)
  color=(green!70!white!90!black)
},
]
\addplot3 [
surf,
variable=\u,
variable y=\v,
domain=-1:1,
domain y=0:360,
]( {cosh(u)*cos(v)} , {cosh(u)*sin(v)} , {sinh(u)} );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Green hyperboloid]

Comment: not being able to set the positions is just a minor issue, thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1: Where are the offsets in the code that you mention in the tex (3cm etc)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: The offsets are in OP's code e.g. in `color(2cm)=(green!70!white!70!black);`

Comment: Thanks! I did not make the connection :).